# Symfony2 JsonResponse and jQuery.parseJson()

Tags: jquery, json, symfony

In my controller if I return a JSON response like:

```
return new JsonResponse(array('numberOfRatings' => count($ratingCollection), 'oldRating' => $oldRating));
```

The returning object will have the following data:

```
protected 'data' => string '{"numberOfRatings":1,"oldRating":2}' (length=35)
```

But when I try to parse this with `jQuery.parseJson();` it will return me an exception that jQuery is not able to parse it. But when I do:

```
return new JsonResponse(json_encode(array('numberOfRatings' => count($ratingCollection), 'oldRating' => $oldRating)));
```

What's equal to

```
return new Response(json_encode(array('numberOfRatings' => count($ratingCollection), 'oldRating' => $oldRating)));
```

The `parseJson()` method works great. But my mistake here cause it seems like `JsonResponse` is useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `JsonResponse`, you don't need to use `jQuery.parseJson()`, the data you got is already a javascript object.

```
$.getJSON(your_url, function(data) {
   // the data is already an object, don't need to parse it.
   // var data = $.parseJSON(data); 
   // ...
});
```